# Ruby TDD with Rspec (Basic Questions)

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I am trying to run a very basic test with Terminal and Sublime Text 3. My simple test runs, but fails (`undefined local variable or method 'x'`)

My folder hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

spec_helper.rb looks like this:

```
require_relative '../test'

require 'yaml'
```

test_spec.rb is extremely basic

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

describe "testing ruby play" do
  it "finds if x is equal to 5" do
    x.should eql 5
  end
end
```

and my test.rb file has `x = 5` That's it.

Will a variable only be recognizable if it's part of a class? And do I need to call a new class every time I run my test?

Comment: please post your class and test.rb file

Comment: That's just it. How do I set up my class so the variable `x` is recognized? For now, all my test.rb file has in it is `x = 5`

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require%20docs)

> **require(name)** → true or false
>
> Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the feature is already
>   loaded.
>
> [snip]
>
> Any constants or globals within the loaded source file will be
>   available in the calling program’s global namespace. However, **local
>   variables will not be propagated to the loading environment.**

You could use a constant in your required file:

```
X = 5
...
X.should eql 5 # => passes
```

But you probably want to do something entirely different here. Perhaps you could expand on the question and explain what you are trying to accomplish.